# Error building apache ambari,HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar

Tags: maven, hadoop, ambari

I am installing apache ambari 2.6.1,I follow the official website steps,[Installation Guide for Ambari 2.6.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.6.1).

When I executed this command, I got an error.

```
mvn -B clean install package jdeb:jdeb -DnewVersion=2.6.1.0.0 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6" -Drat.skip=true
```

ERROR：

```
[INFO] Ambari Main ........................................ SUCCESS [ 25.195 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.290 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web ......................................... SUCCESS [05:01 min]
[INFO] Ambari Views ....................................... SUCCESS [ 13.189 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View .................................. SUCCESS [01:03 min]
[INFO] utility ............................................ SUCCESS [  3.789 s]
[INFO] ambari-metrics ..................................... SUCCESS [  3.440 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common .............................. SUCCESS [ 32.662 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink ......................... FAILURE [ 32.191 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Functional Tests ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Client ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Shell ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-logsearch ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Appender .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Portal ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Solr Client ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Plugin ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Assembly .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Integration Test .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 08:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-29T02:43:35Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 73M/717M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (build-jar) on project ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-common: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink
```

I add -e -X in the command and execute it again.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (build-jar) on project ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-common: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (build-jar) on project ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-common: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-common: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-common: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive (DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:378)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Problem creating jar: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:869)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive (AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:496)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive (DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:378)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/timeline/HadoopTimelineMetricsSink$1.class not found in /home/hduser/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0.0.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect (JarURLConnection.java:142)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream (JarURLConnection.java:150)
    at java.net.URL.openStream (URL.java:1045)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoURLResource.getContents (PlexusIoURLResource.java:30)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiveEntry.getInputStream (ArchiveEntry.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.zipFile (AbstractZipArchiver.java:590)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.addResources (AbstractZipArchiver.java:426)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain (AbstractZipArchiver.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute (AbstractZipArchiver.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:852)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive (AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:496)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive (DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:378)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink
```

My operating system is windows10 subsystem ubuntu.

uname -a

```
Linux YXZX-Lif 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I can not solve this problem, please help me.